# Dynamics CRM 2011 - Run Dialog or Workflow with prompt on EntityCollection

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to create a custom workflow or a custom dialog in Dynamics CRM 2011.

I was able to create a Dialog that prompts for some values and then applies some actions on the selected entity... However, I cannot "run" this dialog when I select more than one entity...

I was also able to create a custom workflow in c# that apply the same actions with "hard-coded" values...

I would like to know how I can:

1. Select multiple entities (Account for example).
2. Have the user prompt for some parameters.
3. Have a workflow or dialog that will update the selected entites with the prompted parameters.

Comment: You're not just performing a bulk edit are you?

Comment: No... There are javascripts on this entity and an onchange event on the field I want to edit. This field is disabled in BulkEdit.

Comment: Ok.  Just wanted to make sure you weren't attempting to recreate bulk edit for no reason.

Comment: You can always add your JS change events during the onload event instead of putting them on the field change event.  That way those fields won't be disabled.

Comment: @AndyMeyers, I understand. However, is there a way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: There isn't anything easily done without some kind of development involved.

Comment: I just created a new entity, with 3 fields and 1 form. I have an onload event on the page load and a onchange event on one of the 3 fields. When I edit a single record, events are fired. When I edit multiple records, events are not fired (I don't care') and the field binded to the onchange event is enabled.... WHY is it enabled now?